# How to trim the last characters from a arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I have an Array of 10 strings:

so now when i get the InnerText from the object,

i want to trim off the last characters of all the strings within the Array

- I have -->
  println(Array)
  Array =
  [User RolesPDF, Create New UserPDFVideo, Create Self-Registration CodePDF, User ManagementPDF, Email SettingsPDF, Download RFIsPDF, Manage Departments & Setup HierarchiesPDFVideo, Tracer Category SetupPDFVideo, Guest Access SetupPDF]

I want to get rid of the PDF (3 characters so the pDF at the end is removed)
Also - Video (8 characters removed)

```
def Array = []

WebUI.comment('Top of Page - For loop for all Text of pdf and videos, and also clicking on all PDFs')

for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    WebUI.delay(1)

    WebUI.scrollToPosition(80, 80)

    String innertext = driver.findElement(By.xpath(('//div[@class=\'content-sections\']/div[1]//div[@class=\'col-12 col-xl-6\']/div[' + 
            i) + ']//div[@class=\'item\']')).getText()

    println(innertext)

    Array << innertext
```

I have tried:

```
def Arraysliced =Array.size
for (int i = 0;i<Array.size;i++){
    Arraysliced[i].substring(0)
    
    println(Arraysliced);
}
String delims = "[ ]+";
String Arraysliced  = Array.split(delims)
Arraysliced = Array
def Arraysliced = []
Arraysliced = Array.split('-'[0])
 (Array.split('-')[0])

 println(Arraysliced)
```

Comment: You could loop through the array and check using `if(String.endsWith("PDF"))` etc, and then substring the results based on the match?

Comment: s.substring(0, s.length() - 3); if the above matches.

Comment: s.indexOf("PDF") or -8 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code-

```
String [] arrsplit  = innertext.split("//PDF");
```

and use arrsplit[0] to add in your code

```
> **Output would be**- if innertext is- Create New UserPDFVideo 
> arrsplit[0]=Create New User  arrsplit[1]=Video //which you need to ignore.
```